# Neo4j Cypher ORDER BY in the middle of the query and expected behaviour on PARALLEL runtime

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-parallel-runtime

In a Cypher query, I can insert `ORDER BY` in the middle of the query, for example

```
MATCH (p:Product)
WITH p
ORDER BY p.id DESC 
LIMIT 5
MATCH (p)-[:CREATED_BY]->(u:User)
RETURN p.id, u.name
```

On the `SLOTTED` or `PIPELINED` runtime, I will receive properly ordered results. For example:

```
p.id | u.name
---------------
5    | someName
4    | someName
3    | someName
2    | someName
1    | someName
```

Should I expect the same result (maintaining the proper order) when using the `PARALLEL` runtime, even if I have additional `MATCH` statements after the `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not guaranteed. Here is what the Cypher manual says about it:

> When ORDER BY is present on a WITH clause , the immediately following
> clause will receive records in the specified order. The order is not
> guaranteed to be retained after the following clause, unless that also
> has an ORDER BY subclause.

Slotted and Pipelined will likely preserve ordering, even if not guaranteed, but Parallel will likely not.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/order-by/#order-with